# Creating two web applications under different host headers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-application, host-header

I am reading a material about SharePoint 2013; “2013 A Core Solutions of Microsoft® SharePoint®
Server 2013”. And on one of the examples they want to create two web applications representing two departments sales & finance. And what they do is that they created two web applications for these departments. But the thing I did not understand is that the sales web application was created under “Sales.local” host header, while the finance was created under “finance.contoso.com” host header. 
So generally speaking why would I in real scenario crate two web applications under two different host headers ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the advantages of using host header is that it allows you to create different web applications at the same port number. In the example you provided both applications will be created at port 80.

Comment: ok i see . you are right both web applications were created at port 80 . but should "sales.local" and "finanace.contoso.com" represents real domains , or they are just labels ?

Comment: I think, they can represent two different domains.

Comment: you mean they can represents real domain, but they do not have to  ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.